# XMLHTTPRequest used asynchronously polling the readyState

Tags: c++, delphi, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code:

```
var
  xhttp: OleVariant;

xhttp := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
xhttp.Open('GET', URL, True);
xhttp.send();

while xhttp.readyState <> 4 do
begin
  Application.HandleMessage;        
end;

// status property is available only when readyState is complete
if (xhttp.Status = 200) then... 
// do something
```

In this situation I do not want to use the event `onreadystatechange`.

**The Question:**
Is it safe to poll on the `readyState` for a value of 4, **after** I call `Send`, or is there a risk to be stuck in an endless loop?

---

**Some facts:**

The [ServerXMLHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms765535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can use a `waitForResponse` inside the loop, but I want to use `XMLHTTPRequest` component.
It is stated there that:

> The waitForResponse method is more efficient than polling the
>   readyState property, which is the only way to wait for an asynchronous
>   send using the XMLHTTP component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about an endless loop, then simply implement a timeout for your loop, eg:

```
var 
  xhttp: OleVariant; 
  Ticks: DWORD;

  function TimeoutElapsed: Boolean;
  var
    Cur, Elapsed: DWORD;
  begin
    Cur := GetTickCount();
    if Cur >= Ticks then
      Elapsed := Cur - Ticks
    else
      Elapsed := (MAXDWORD - Ticks) + Cur;
    Result := (Elapsed >= 15000);
  end;

begin
  xhttp := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); 
  xhttp.Open('GET', URL, True); 
  xhttp.send(); 

  Ticks := GetTickCount();
  while (xhttp.readyState <> 4) and (not TimeoutElapsed()) do
  begin
    if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, nil, False, 1000, QS_ALLINPUT) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      Application.ProcessMessages();         
    Ticks := GetTickCount();
  end; 

  // status property is available only when readyState is complete 
  if xhttp.readyState = 4 then
  begin
    if (xhttp.Status = 200) then...  
  end;
end;
```

Comment: actually I was planing on adding a timeout like this (more or less). why do we need the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects, rather then using Application.HandleMessage?

Comment: It is not a good idea to call `Application.ProcessMessages()`, or even `Application.HandleMessage()`, in a tight loop like you were originally doing.  It is very inefficient, and is known to cause various problems.  `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` can tell you when there are pending messages.  There is no point in calling `Application.ProcessMessages()` or `Application.HandleMessage()` when there is nothing to process yet.

Comment: `MsgWaitForMultipleObjcts()` also puts the calling thread into an efficient sleep state until a message arrives or the specified timeout elapses, giving the `XMLHTTP` object more time slices to do its background work.

Comment: If you are calling it in the context of the main thread, then potentially yes, assuming there are no pending messages in the main message queue.  `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` wakes up immediately if a message arrives in the queue before the 1000ms timeout elapses.  Using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` in the loop does not change the fact that the loop itself is blocking the calling thread anyway, it just makes the loop work more efficiently by not repeatedly pumping the message queue unnecessarily, that's all.

Comment: I think the extra `Ticks := GetTickCount();` inside the loop will prevent the loop from exiting in case of time out. or did I missed something?